# Is there any way to create an Excel File using an Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a table with this columns: name, surname, email, location and number with their respective data.

Is possible generate an Excel using an Stored Procedure in Azure SQL Database and store this file in my desktop with the results of my querie? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, for example you can generate xml document using Office OpenXML format which MS Excel supports. https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/open-xml-formats-and-file-name-extensions-5200d93c-3449-4380-8e11-31ef14555b18

Comment: I created an example on https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/query-to-excel-stored-procedure

Answer (score 1):

*"Is there any way to create an Excel File using an Stored Procedure?"*: Yes.

An SP can do anything and that you can do with T-SQL. How you create the Excel spreadsheet is up to you; SSIS, SSRS, CLR, `xp_cmdshell`,etc are just a few methods. You'll just need to put the appropriate query and statements in your SP, ensure you have the correct permissions and ensure the service account(s) have the appropriate permissions.

If you're asking *how* to create an Excel file using SQL Server, that is a completely different question.

Comment: Yes, I would like to know the code, bucase I'm using an Azure Sql Database and I'm having some problems with the error that is not supported in my version of Sql Server

Comment: Those are all things you don't mention in your question at all @jnoguerm . If you're trying to do something on Azure (which you haven't tagged), and getting an error why are you aren't you asking about that? You should post a **new** question, tagging the appropriate technologies, show your code, explain your goal(s), and show any errors your getting or describe why the process isn't working as your expect.

Answer (score 0):

In Azure SQL database, most of the ways to export data to an Excel file with T-SQL, such as [`xp_cmdshell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)、[`OPENROWSET`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)(Managed instance only) are not suppported. Even if there's no error when creating the stored procedure, the error will happen after EXEC it.

You will get the error like:

> "XXX is not supported in this version of SQL Server".

For local SQL Server, you can reference this [tutorial](https://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=49926). This tutorial provides a demo stored  procedure code for you.

Azure SQL database also provides many other ways to export the data to excel files.
For example, [Export SQL table to Excel using SSMS](https://sqlbak.com/blog/export-sql-table-to-excel/).  Using the sql statements to select the data your want to the excel file.

Or you can connect to the Azrue SQL database from your new excel file, get the data you want with sql statements. Please reference the Azure tutorial: [Connect Excel to a single database in Azure SQL database and create a report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-excel)

Hope this helps.

[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)